# Foreach loop problem for IQueryable object

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Can we use foreach loop for `IQueryable` object?

I'd like to do something as follow:

```
query = IQueryable<Myclass> = objDataContext.Myclass; // objDataContext is an object of LINQ datacontext class

int[] arr1 = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 };

foreach (int i in arr1)
{
     query = query.Where(q => (q.f_id1 == i || q.f_id2 == i || q.f_id3 == i));
}
```

I get a wrong output as each time value of `i` is changed.

Comment: What "output"? Nothing is being output here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're facing is deferred execution, you should be able to find a lot of information on this but basically none of the code s being executed until you actually try to read data from the IQueryable (Convert it to an IEnumerable or a List or other similar operations). This means that this all happens after the foreach is finished when i is set to the final value.

If I recall correctly one thing you can do is initialize a new variable inside the for loop like this:

```
foreach (int i in arr1)
{
   int tmp = i;
   query = query.Where(q => (q.f_id1 == tmp || q.f_id2 == tmp || q.f_id3 == tmp));
}
```

By putting it in a new variable which is re-created each loop, the variable should not be changed before you execute the `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a for each, try it like this:

```
query = objDataContext.Myclass.Where(q => (arr1.Contains(q.f_id1) || arr1.Contains(q.f_id2) || arr1.Contains(q.f_id3));
```

Comment: logically it'll give incorrect filter, try to run that query in SQL!

Comment: see this two queries are different:

select * from MyClass where (f_id1 = 1 or f_id2 = 1 or f_id3 = 1) 
and (f_id1 = 3 or f_id2 = 3 or f_id3 = 3);
select * from MyClass where (f_id1 in (1,3) or f_id2 in (1,3) or f_id3 in (1,3))

Answer (score 0):

this is because "`i`" is not evaluated until you really use the iterate the query collectionif not by that time I believe  "`i`"  will be the last.